# Difference in the properties for the same dll in c#.net and vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am adding a dll for my project. My project is in vb.net and dll is written in c#.net. 
When I add this to a vb.net project the properties that are available are different (less in number) to the properties that are available if the same dll is added to a c# project.

> **Object Browser view when added to a VB.Net Project** [image]
>
> **Object Browser view when added to a c# project** [image: Object Browser view when added to a c# project]

If you see in c# view you can access properties like "hits" and "facets" which are not accessible in vb.net.

Can anyone please help me understand this issue.

Comment: Might your DLL be out of date? Maybe hits and facets have been added recently and you are using a DLL in your VB project which was compiled before hand?

Comment: How are `hits` and `facets` defined? Is there anything unusual about them?

Comment: Some types, e.g. `uint`, are not available to VB.

Comment: Capitalize your property names :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Can you please expand on your comment.  VB allows `Dim i As UInteger = 42` for example.

Comment: @dittu - Do you, perhaps, have "Hide Advanced Members" turned on in VS for VB.Net?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I tried turning of Hide Advanced Members and it didn't help. I downloaded the source code for the above mentioned dll from github and I am trying to make it CLS-complaint by changing the property names.

Comment: @dittu - You won't be able to make a reference that has a `uint` propery CLS compliant.  This is because `uint` is of the type `System.Uint32` which is not CLS compliant.  The answer to your question is to use `System.Uint32` in your C# code.

Comment: @Ramhound There are no unsigned integers.

Comment: @dittu - Yes...There is actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561557/what-is-the-uint32-data-type-in-visual-basic-net?rq=1 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: @ChrisDunaway What I really meant was that `uint` cannot be used by code that requires CLS-Compliance, but I guess if VB has the same type but with a different name, it should be able to use it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - There are CLS alternatives documented by MSDN.  `System.Int64` would be the CLS compliant alternative to `System.UInt32` and `Decmial` would be the alternative to `System.UInt64`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are differences between VB.NET and C#. Make sure you compile your C# dll with the assembly attribute [CLSCompliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute.aspx) set to true so your compiler can determine if all your publics are compatible to the other .NET languages.

Comment: This answer does not make a great deal of sense.  VB.NET and C# generate the same CL code when compiled

Comment: @Ramhound, what would you expect VB to do with a C# uint, not having an unsigned int type of it's own?

Comment: You would just use `UInt32`. **Int32 and int are exactly the same value type.** I am going to issue a downvote for the first sentence. It should be stated that neither `Uint32` nor `uint` are CLS compliant.

Comment: -1. .NET is not .NET? What is it then? If `a != a`, we got a major logical problem here. :)

Comment: @Ramhound I changed my first sentence. I'm not here to argue about our differing understanding of english as a means to transport fun.

Comment: @Neolisk I changed my first sentence. I'm not here to argue about our differing understanding of english as a means to transport fun.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my situation I am using a dll downloaded from github. When I downloaded the source code from github I found out that it is not CLSComplaint. When I changed the property name and added DataMember attribute (for jsonserilzation) all the properties are available in vb.net project as well, but the problem I will be facing is merging of the code changes to any updates in the particular class library in original version to the CLSComplaint one which I don't want to commit to GitHub until I speak with author.

As a work around I added GetHitCount(CLSComplaint property name)

```
public int GetHitCount
{
    get { return hits.total;}
}
```

this exposes the "hits" property which is not available when the dll is added to vb.net project.

Comment: If you want a CLS compliant unsigned integer then you need to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx instead of the unsigned integer the original code used.  Your accepted answer is actually wrong.  As I pointed out VB.NET and C# are compiled into the same code ( when CLS code is used of course ).

Comment: @Ramhound all the integers in the particular class I am looking into are System.Int32 type there are no unsigned(Uint32 types). I might have misunderstood your comment. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: I could have sworn your original question was asking about two properties that were unsigned integers.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that "hits" and "facets" in the C# project have members in the class that have the same name, but different case.  This is a very common issue for VB projects referencing C# dlls, and it also will result in the C# dll not being CLS Compliant.  VB is case-insensitive, so it cannot determine which "hits" is being needed if there also is a "Hits" member - as a result VB will not display either member.

You can still call "hits" and "facets", but you will need to use "InvokeMember" to do this (using reflection).